# Umbraco Preview not showing the correct content

Tags: owin, umbraco7

When I have the following key in my web.config, umbraco preview is working fine, showing me the correct content but I can not login to my web site, I can login to umbraco backoffice without any problem.

When I comment out the following key, then I can login to my web site but this time umbraco preview is not showing the correct content.

What should I do to make preview work and at the same time I can login to my front end site? I have already searched for a solution, but I haven't managed to fix this so far. Any help is appreciated.

Umbraco version 7.4.3 assembly: 1.0.5948.18141

The key:

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup" />
```

My OwinStartup class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(OwinStartup), "Configuration")]
namespace ABC.XYZ.Site
{
    public class OwinStartup : UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup
    {
        public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            base.Configuration(app);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions());


            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                var loggedInMarkerCookie = context.Request.Cookies[Settings.CookieLoggedInMarkerName];
                var autoLoginAttempt = context.Request.Cookies[Settings.CookieLoggedInMarkerAttemptName];

                if (!context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/sso/") && (loggedInMarkerCookie != null && autoLoginAttempt == null))
                {
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append(Settings.CookieLoggedInMarkerAttemptName, DateTime.Now.ToString(), new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30) });
                    context.Authentication.Challenge();
                }

                return next.Invoke();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your App Setting needs to be:

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="ABC.XYZ.Site, OwinStartup" />
```

And looking at the [source](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/5397f2c53acbdeb0805e1fe39fda938f571d295a/src/Umbraco.Web/UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup.cs#L56) I think that you need to call `base.Configuration(app);` after you've added your custom configuration.

Comment: Thanks Jason for the answer, one up for your time to answer this question but unfortunately your suggestion doesn't fix my problem.